# Route with non-English characters doesn't work with Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use routes with non-English characters (Russian cyrillic) and these routes work just fine:

```
Route::resource('франшизы/подкатегории', 'Franch\SubCategoryController');
```

However when I'm trying to use same route with `Form::` construction and sending the form, I get a `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` exception:

```
// generates: http://localhost:8000/франшизы/подкатегории/20/edit?
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Get', 'route' => array('франшизы.подкатегории.edit', $subCategory->id))) !!}
```

I've copy-pasted code and added new route and `Form::` with English only characters which works just fine:

```
// generates: http://localhost:8000/franch/sub/20/edit?
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'Get', 'route' => array('franch.sub.edit', $subCategory->id))) !!}

Route::resource('franch/sub', 'Franch\SubCategoryController');
```

My question is how can I make non-English routes work? If it's impossible, what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this questions at four forums, but noone was able to help me with it. I still do not know the best solution to the issue, but I have done this:

```
Route::get('франшизы/подкатегории', 'Franch\SubCategoryController@index')->name('franch_sub_categories_index');
Route::resource('franchises/subcategories', 'Franch\SubCategoryController', ['except' => ['index']]);
```

And it works just fine.

- I'm using URL with utf-8 characters in **the first route** for the simple
  `@index` requests which is important for SEO and URL readability.
- **The
  second route** handles all RESTful requries.

Hope it'll be helpful for some of you.

Comment: Did you find a betters solution for this? I was using Lumen and foreign language worked just fine for slugs, but just switch our API to Laravel, and only english slugs work, the rest 404s.